# How do I interface PyUSB and the OV534 sensor

Tags: python, usb

My main goal is to be able to talk to the Hercules Dualpix Exchange webcam through USB on my computer so that I can better understand the protocol and its needs. I've done some research and found that this specific webcam uses the OV534 image processor which has its own USB protocol. It seems as though the OV534 utilizes the USB Video Class/USB Audio Class which made me feel like this was going to be easy to interface. But it's actually quite the opposite...

I've been able to connect to the device via USB and transfer some data (I can request configuration), but barely anything else works. My goal right now is to turn on the internal LED, but even that doesn't work. I've been trying to mimic how the OV534 module does things in UVC, but none of my read/writes are doing anything (except timing out and not having enough bmAttributes).

Does anybody have any insight as to what my problem is? It is possible that I'm not using PyUSB correctly, but I've been trying to set registers the same exact way they do in this code. My read/write functions are

```
def reg_read(dev, reg):
    requestType=(0x01) | (usb.util.CTRL_IN) | (usb.util.CTRL_TYPE_STANDARD)#(0x80)|(0x02 << 5)|(0x01)
    request=0x1
    value=0x0
    index=reg
    byt=20
    timeout=2000

    #ret = dev.ctrl_transfer(requestType, request, value, index, byt, timeout)
    ret = dev.ctrl_transfer(requestType, request, value, index, byt, timeout)
    return ret

def reg_write(dev, reg, data):
    requestType=(0x01) | (usb.util.CTRL_OUT) | (usb.util.CTRL_TYPE_STANDARD) #(0x80)|(0x02 << 5)|(0x01)
    request=0x1
    value=0x0
    index=reg
    dat=data
    timeout=2000

    #ret = dev.ctrl_transfer(requestType, request, value, index, dat, timeout)
    ret = dev.ctrl_transfer(requestType, request, value, index, dat, timeout)
    return ret
```

As a reference, this is the OV534.c code (https://git.linuxtv.org/pinchartl/uvcvideo.git/tree/drivers/media/video/gspca/ov534.c?id=fbb4c6d20f29f2b10daad31cc6238d91f93d70d4)

Comment: I'm afraid the device isn't UVC. Otherwise it wouldn't sit inside of the gspca folder. P.s. "OV534" is also not the sensor (which is pretty logic-agnostic by itself) but the camera "processor".